# linux batch rename directories and strip # character from name

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

i have a directory with a lot of subdirectories with a # infront of them:

```
#adhasdk
#ad18237
```

I want to rename them all and remove the # caracter
I tried to do:

```
rename -n `s/#//g` *
```

but didn't seem to work.

```
-bash: s/#//g: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use

```
$ rename 's/^#//' *
```

use -n just to check that what you think it would happen really happens.
In you example you have the clue about the wrong quotes used (backticks) in the error message

```
 -bash: s/#//g: No such file or directory
```

bash is trying to execute a command named `s/#//g`.

No that using `g` (global) and not anchoring the regular expression you will replace any `#`, not just the one in the first position.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether it's just a typo when you typed it here, but that "rename" command should work if:

1. you leave off the "-n" and
2. you quote the substitution with regular single-quotes and not back-quotes

The "-n" tells it to not really do anything.  The back-quotes are just wrong (they mean something but not what you want here).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use backticks (`). You should use normal quotes:

```
rename -n 's/#//g' *
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for DIR in \#*/
do
     echo mv "$DIR" "${DIR/#\#/}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to rename all folders inside a given folder. Each folder name had some text inside round braces. The following command removed the round braces from all folder names:

rename 's/(.+)//' *

Answer (score 0):

Some distros doesn't support regexp in `rename`. You have to install `prename`. Even more, sometimes you can't install `prename` and you have to install `gprename` to have binary `prename`.

If you have 'prename' then just change backtick character "  `  " to single quote and everything should work.

So the solution should be:

```
prename -n 's/#//g' *
```

or

```
prename -n 'y/#//' *
```