# Rename a bunch of folders

Tags: regex, windows, unix, cygwin

I have a bunch of folders in the same directory

```
2012-12-06 Camcorder_5th_Jan_2013
2012-12-07 Camcorder_5th_Jan_2013
2012-12-16 Camcorder_5th_Jan_2013
...
```

I wish to drop the Camcorder_5th_Jan_2013 part and for them to look like:

```
2012-12-06 
2012-12-07
2012-12-16 
...
```

I was thinking something like

```
> mv (*).Camcorder* 1
```

i.e. capture everything before Camcorder and put into group 1 and rename to this group.

But I am struggling.

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that you can either have "folders in a folder", "directories in a directory", or a psychosis of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

replace match `\s.+` with empty string

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow that

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `rename`, I am currently not in front of my Linux machine but hopefully these two links can get you somewhere:

**Howto: Linux Rename Multiple Files At a Shell Prompt**

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html

[linux batch rename directories and strip # character from name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417339/linux-batch-rename-directories-and-strip-caracter-from-name)

Update:
If you have access to Gnome or the X-Environment maybe you could try something like this if the Bash syntax is giving you a headache.

**Métamorphose : A File -n- Folder Renamer:**
http://file-folder-ren.sourceforge.net

Comment: That's files not folders